# How to apply different styles to ListBox header and item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a `ListBox` which is bound to my custom class

```
ObservableCollection<FieldPropertyItem> _fieldOrderCollection`;
```

```
internal struct FieldPropertyItem
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string AliasName { get; set; }
}
```

Code for ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="FieldOrderListBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectedIndex="0"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" SelectionChanged="FieldOrderListBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="#FF479EF3"></SolidColorBrush>
    </ListBox.Resources>

       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="MyTemplate">
            <Grid  Margin="-5,-1,0,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="FieldName" MinWidth="5" MaxWidth="300"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MaxWidth="350"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                                

                <Border  BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0.5,0.0,0.5,0.5" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0" ToolTip="{Binding Name}" Margin="2,0,2,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Black" Margin="-2,0,-1,0"/>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0.0,0.5,0.5" Margin="-2,0,0,0" Padding="0,5,0,0" Grid.Column="2">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AliasName}" Grid.Column="1" ToolTip="{Binding AliasName}" Margin="2,0,2,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Now i want that my ListBox first item should look like header. The remaining ones should have a light dim background.

Comment: See the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to see how code is formatted.

Comment: I have a few solutions in mind, but may I ask first why, if there seems to be a notion of hierarchy, why aren't you using a control that supports this notion, such as a `TreeView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the previous item is `null` using a `RelativeSource` binding in a trigger, e.g. this `DataTemplate` makes the first element bold:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" />
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding AliasName}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

*(Use shared size groups as shown above to align the grids with one-another, set `Grid.IsSharedSizeGroup` to `true` on the `ListBox` element)*

I would not recommend doing this by the way, if your item collection contains the header there is definitely something wrong with your data-design.

Answer (score 0):

1.) You can have a new Property IsFirstItem on your FieldPropertyItem
Whenever your _fieldOrderCollection changes determine the IsFirtItem Property of the elements in your ObservableCollection.

2.) Define the corresponding Templates in XAML (Normal and FirstItem Template)

3.) You can then bind in XAML like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"  >
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource normalTemplate}"/>
      <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsFirstItem}" Value="True" >
          <Setter TargetName="contentControl" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource firstItemTemplate}"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
      </DataTemplate.Triggers>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```